# Method reference results in raw-type compiler warning, but lambda does not

Tags: java, generics, lambda, method-reference

Given:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<? extends List<? extends T>> supplyAllOf(
    List<? extends CompletableFuture<? extends T>> input)
{
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(input.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[input.size()])).
        thenApply(ignored -> input.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

I am getting this compiler warning (using `-Xlint`):

```
found raw type: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
  missing type arguments for generic class java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<T>
```

but if I replace `CompletableFuture::join` with `e -> e.join()` the warning goes away.

Is this a compiler bug? If not, why am I seeing this behavior?

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal Thanks for the head's up. It sounds like a compiler bug to me. Further, I can't figure out how to apply Holger's workaround for my case. I'll let this issue stew for a couple of days and file a bug report if no answer is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not *entirely sure*, but looks like [this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8063054) (or at least a use case of it).

Either way this is fixed in `10` (just tested it) and it does not produce any warnings.